# How can i refactor the position of parameters of a function in the whole program

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, refactoring

I have a function such as this:

```
function doSomething(A, B, C) {
}
```

I have used this function numerous times throughout the program like this:

```
doSomething(input1, input2, input3)
```

Is there a way to refactor this function so it becomes like this:

```
function doSomething(B, A, C) {
}

doSomething(input2, input1, input3)
```

You might ask why I need this, this function takes many more parameters then what I showed and the placement doesn't make sense!, I have to always pass null to reach the most used parameters, it would be awesome if I could just swap the position of these parameters in the function and of course throughout the whole program!
I don't mind using any third-party software if they are able to do something like this
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to replace them. Click `Ctrl+shift+F` then expand panel. Write `doSomething\((.*?),(.*?),(.*?)\)` this one to first row. Then this one to second row `doSomething($2,$1,$3)`. You can then replace them one by one quickly or replace them all(I wouldn't do that).

Comment: I knew about regex being used in replace and etc, but i didn't know i could actually use the groups with `${groupNumber}` and place them wherever i want to !, Thanks!